# How to add a footer into popup with jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

When I add a footer into the popup dynamically, the footer is inside the popup `div` in DOM, but in the Google Chrome page, I see the footer is on the bottom of the page.

Do I need some special attributes for the footer `div` when I add it into a popup?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tell jQM to enhance the new content after appending it to the footer. e.g.:

```
$("#popupDialog").append('<div data-role="footer"><h1>Popup Footer</h1></div>').enhanceWithin();
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/th009hd7/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand how to put the footer under popup now. But when the popup has already been shown, I want to add a footer dynamically. My problem is after I add the footer under popup, the popup view can not be infront of the page any more. I need to re-show the popup... what should I do to keep the popup always infront ?

Comment: @Ivy_Hope, here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/th009hd7/2/ It seems to work fine adding the footer after showing the popup. Can you change the fiddle to reproduce the problem?